# VBA - Macro how do I make a pivot table where it screens for the column title and inserts it next to the values

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I need the Bold numbers (e.g. 14) on the left side of the numbers starting with 6.... (those are accounts) and every time a new Header starts (e.g. 31) I need this number to change.

I want to program a macro but I can't figure out how to do this, especially since the number of accounts changes almost everytime so I can't just use a fixed range.

I would appreciate if anyone might be able to help me.

[image]

Comment: You cannot manually edit the result of a pivot table. Any such attempt would be futile (as you pointed out) because the pivot table changes each time with the underlying data. So, if you want the pivot table to change then you should work on the underlying data. If that's not an option then you might want to use PowerQuery to joins your source table with a transformation table which contains the "change values".

Comment: Thanks for the Response I don't want to Change the Pivot table I just want the value (14) copied next to the accounts, which means in a cell next to it, so not in the Pivot table itself. But the real Problem is, is it possible for Excel to Change to the next Header in the Pivot table (31) and copy it next to the cells without having to manually Change the value?

Comment: If you just want some data from the pivot table to be copied across then you should do that manually and make use of the VBA macro recorder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_HQGHPBYoo. Afterwards, have a look at the code and try to understand it by highlighting VBA key-words and pressing `F1`. The resulting code could be run as part of the `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate` event. Then your data would get copied over each time the pivot table changes.

Comment: I have coded macros manually before, so I know how to use the macro Recorder it is more of a language barrier kind of Thing, but basically I try to come up with a macro that doesn't only insert a Pivot table from a certain range but knows when to Change the value that is supposed to be inserted next to the numbers

Comment: But I will just put a stop in the macro, do that Task manually and then let the rest of the macro execute! Anyways thanks a lot for your help and your time!

Comment: If you want the Bold values to repeat for every row, you can change the Pivot table to Tabular View. On the Design Tab, under Report Layout, select "Show in Tabular View" and "Repeat All Item Labels".

Comment: @PaaquaGrant that was exactly what I was looking for thanks!